# How to suppress adjusting a column width in a gridview

Tags: asp.net

I know my question has been asked before but I still have no answer.

I have a gridview with AutoGenerateColumns="False". The width of every column is set explicitly with the HeaderStyle-Width and ItemStyle-Width properties.

What happens is that if the data coming to a BoundField column contains some multi-word text, the width of the column gets adjusted by the maximum width of the words. For example, if there are two rows in the dataset: "Hello World" and "I like programming", the grid will be adjusted by the word "programming".

I've tried to play with the Wrap properties but it doesn't help.

Can you please help?
Thanks
LG

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the HeaderStyle-CssClass and ItemStyle-CssClass to a CSS class which you can use to set the required width:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="restricted-width-column" ItemStyle-CssClass="restricted-width-column" ...

...

<style type="text/css">
    .restricted-width-column
    {
        width:50px;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It turned out that the width of the grid was set less than the total widths of its columns. I increased the width of the grid and the problem disappeared.